# Enhancing core WordPress code for private and public projects?

Tags: licensing, core-modifications

I am having a hard time interpreting the WordPress license when it comes to core code. I have extracted one component, the WordPress Hooks system, and I have enhanced it in very specific ways to make it usable in my private projects.

I am considering making the code available on GitHub and Packagist.

I also want to use it for code I develop for a client, installing it via Composer.

I have several questions I can't find a good answer for:

1. Am I OK to publish my version of the code on GitHub/Packagist?
2. If so, I presume I need to use the same license? For instance, I
   cannot change the license to MIT, which is what I would like to do?
3. Is my client's code (internal use and public facing only; nothing
   developed for resale) affected in any way by using this component?
   I'm pretty much using commercial, self-developed or MIT licensed
   components throughout.

Thanks for any guidance. There is so much conflicting advice out there, and most of it is regarding themes and plugins; I can't find anything about the WordPress core.

Comment: This is a question that you should ask a lawyer not coders

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WordPress is licensed under [GPLv2 according to their website](https://wordpress.org/about/license/). Answers to your questions, under the GPL:

> 1) Am I OK to publish my version of the code on GitHub/Packagist?

Yes, as long as you keep a copy of the GPLv2 license with your released code.

> 2) If so, I presume I need to use the same license? For instance, I cannot change the license to MIT, which is what I would like to do?

This I'm unsure of, and the [GNU GPLv2 FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.en.html#ModifyGPL) isn't incredibly clear on the topic, at least in terms of changing the license. My best guess is that you would have to remain under the GPLv2 license, with no ability to change to a different license.

> 3) Is my client's code (internal use and public facing only; nothing developed for resale) affected in any way by using this component? I'm pretty much using commercial, self-developed or MIT licensed components throughout.

Again, I'd refer to the FAQ as it might be more helpful than I am. If you're using GPL code and want to distribute any part of your code, you must include the source and a copy of the GPL. As far as usage, I don't know that you need to make any changes to how you are doing things now.

You may be able to get some answers from [these GNU-related IRC channels](http://www.gnu.org/server/irc-rules.en.html), or find a lawyer who specializes in free software licensing. You can also probably find forums that provide this information or discussion about it for free.

Legal disclaimer to the above advice: **I am not a lawyer**

Comment: THank you for your response. I note that on Drupal's website (https://www.drupal.org/about/licensing, linked from WP's site) they say "The GPL requires that if you make a derivative work of Drupal and distribute it to someone else, you must provide that person with the source code under the terms of the GPL so that they may modify and redistribute it under the terms of the GPL as well". I interpret this as meaning the client can then take my source and give it away for free. Would that be true for the WHOLE codebase, or just for a part of it?

Comment: Downvoted as an answer that contains "but don't trust me on this" can not be authorative :(